# When terminal objects are separators?

Tags: category-theory

In category of **Set** the terminal object is also a separator (or generator). But this is not correct in general category. What condition would guarantee that the terminal object of a category if exists is also a separator?
I thought of this one: Any morphism $!:C\rightarrow T $ can be extended uniquely along $u: C \rightarrow A$ for any object $A$.
Many Thanks

Comment: Your claim is false even in $\mathbf{Set}$: take $A = \emptyset$. I doubt there is any good characterisation of the terminal object being a separator.

Comment: Thanks Zhen. But the claim has failed in a very special case (I mean what could possibly be an extension along the `no morphism'). i.e., the unique extension is there as much as the $u:\rightarrow \emptyset$ is there. Can you plz think of any other counterexample or correct me if I am wrong. thanks

Comment: You might be able to get around this glitch by looking at the category of pointed sets (the slice category over a point).

Comment: The category of pointed sets is no example. I agree with Zhen, I doubt that there is any good characterization. And besides, I think that this property is satisfied only in rather boring categories.

Comment: A reformulation could be that the functor $\hom(T,-)$ is faithful (but it does say exactly the same as "T is a separator"). The notion of [well-pointed](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-pointed+topos) topos can help you in your search. But from what I read, it seems that well-pointed topos is more often sufficient to resemble $\mathbf{Sets}$ than necessary (you can look at Mac Lane and Moerdijk's book _Sheaves in Geometry and Logic_).